# GDAL/OGR Determine if dataset is raster or vector

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector, ogr

I am writing a script using the GDAL/OGR Python bindings and it is possible that the user may provide a raster dataset or a vector dataset as input.  If the user provides a vector dataset, the script will convert it to raster.

Is there a way to determine whether the dataset is raster or vector before opening them?

I could just try to open the dataset with OGR first and if it returns None I could try to open with GDAL, but I am looking for a more simple way like `gdal.IsRaster(filepath)` if it exists.

Comment: Could you not check the file extension before doing anything else?

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum is spot on.  If you want a 'clean' looking line, how about wrapping your try except into a function and calling that function.  Also, I believe GDAL 2.0 was/is considering a merge of gdal and ogr.

Comment: @DarrenCope - I could check the file extension, but then my script would have to know exactly which file extensions are raster and which are vector.  Thats a lot of constants to include in the script.

Comment: File extensions are meaningless. They are just indicators for humans to see. You can name files however you like without changing their contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now, there are two separate set of APIs for [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) and [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html). Thus, the method you describe (try to open with OGR first and if it fails, open with GDAL) would be current way of doing it.